# setTimeout callback executing immediately

Tags: node.js, settimeout

I'm working on something in nodejs that involves checking times in a database on the minute every minute. To do this, I've got a settimeout when first starting the server to get my setInterval to be as close to on the minute as possible. However, the settimeout callback, which starts my setinterval, is firing immediately, rather than waiting at all.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('starting time checks');
  setInterval(afterdelay,60*1000);
}, 60-new Date(Date.now()).getSeconds());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `setTimeout` callback is the time, in milliseconds, the timer should wait before the specified function or code is executed:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('starting time checks');
  setInterval(afterdelay, 60*1000);
}, 60000);
```

But, if you want to run `afterdelay` function a minute after app starts, you could use `setInterval` without `setTimeout`:

```
setInterval(afterdelay, 60000);
```

Comment: I did seconds instead of miliseconds. Thanks.